# Is there a way right click on chrome to bring up the context menu when the debugger is stopped on a breakpoint?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, node-webkit

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask. I looked around and stackoverflow made the most sense to me. Plus it is a question that can be answered.

The specific task that I want to accomplish is I am working on an app in nw.js (it's like electron). To reload the app I right click on the page and the usual context menu comes up (the one with "inspect") and there is an option to reload the page.

When the debugger is stopped on a breakpoint that context menu doesn't show up. So in order to reload the app I have to move the mouse somewhere on the screen to close dev tools and then mouse back to the window to reload it. It makes working so much more tedious and while it only takes a moment it feels like an eternity.

Are there any flags in chrome or plugins or nw.js settings that will save me from doing this 763,000 times a day?